# Get Textbox values from a datalist or repeater on postback

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a usercontrol that will have a datalist or repeater. This data control (datalist or repeater) will have all of its rows in edit mode and I need to get the values entered by the user after he submits the page that contains this usercontrol (the page will have 3 instances of the same usercontrol).

How can I do this?

I'm looking for previous question on StackOverflow, but I can't find one about a data control with all rows in edit mode.